# FFmpeg concat after overlay's (append)

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

I have some video to witch i need to concat a header and add some overlay's, the problem is that i need to do the overlay's first becouse otherwise the time woundn't be correct, and only afterwards concat the header to the begining of the video

```
ffmpeg -i talk.mp4  -i start_pancarte.png -i end_pancarte.png  -i logo_alpha.png  -i header.mp4-filter_complex\ 
" overlay= enable='between(t,0,3.04)' [x];\
[x] overlay = enable='between(t,495.64, 498.6)' [y];\
[y] overlay=15:15:enable='between(t,3.04,495.64)'[c];\
[c] concat " solution.mp4
```

This obviously adds the header to the end and I need it in the front, how do I do this (in 1 command)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i talk.mp4 -i start_pancarte.png -i end_pancarte.png -i logo_alpha.png -i header.mp4
  -filter_complex
"[0][1]overlay= enable='between(t,0,3.04)'[x];\
 [x][2]overlay=enable='between(t,495.64, 498.6)'[y];\
 [y][3] overlay=15:15:enable='between(t,3.04,495.64)'[c];\
 [4][c]concat" solution.mp4
```

Relying on implicit filter pad connections can be sloppy, as you have discovered. I've made the inputs to each filter explicit and arranged the inputs to the concat in the required order.